# Any idea what's the OCR tool behind `myfonts.com/WhatTheFont` font recognizer?

Tags: ocr

I went to `myfonts.com/WhatTheFont` to get the font from a text to train tesseract.
I realized that the font recognizer did actually better OCR than when I used tesseract on the same image.
So any idea how could I find out what OCR tool or library they're using?
They do have a *forum* but it's not a support forum, it's more like a font marketplace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this question is off-topic, but [this page](https://books.google.com/books?id=S6piGFy2T5IC&pg=PA433&lpg=PA433&dq=%60myfonts.com/WhatTheFont%60%20OCR%20algorithm&source=bl&ots=hJ5oJ_3Gxh&sig=HhC65MWJh6K6yfYKXF7ukwJXQ_0&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjy9d7JnqbZAhVIIsAKHb25Ao8Q6AEISTAE#v=onepage&q=%60myfonts.com%2FWhatTheFont%60%20OCR%20algorithm&f=false) suggests that the algorithm is described in:

[image]

Comment: Thanks. What stack site would be on-topic for OCR related questions?

Comment: @Petruza : No idea. That's why I answered it and didn't close immediately. :-)